# WCF service:400 bad request?

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, wcf, http-status-code-400

I am working  on wcf from 7 days.I  created one  Wcf Service. 
But is working fine and got response in visual studio by adding service reference. But my problem is whenever it is integrated in  android/windows, those people are not getting response. They are getting 400 (bad request).   Please any one help me how  i get proper response. (i want response as json) this is  my below code.
 Thank you in advance.

in interface

```
public interface ISampleService1
    {
        [OperationContract]

         [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "getdata",BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
         string getdata();
}
```

in class

```
 public  string getdata()
        {
            try
            {


                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con2"].ConnectionString);
                SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("select CircleID, CircleName from Circle", con);
                con.Open();
                comm.ExecuteNonQuery();

                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(comm);
                // DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);

                JavaScriptSerializer JSSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
                List<Dictionary<string, object>> DtRows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
                Dictionary<string, object> newrow = null;

                //Code to loop each row in the datatable and add it to the dictionary object
                foreach (DataRow drow in dt.Rows)
                {
                    newrow = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                    {
                        newrow.Add(col.ColumnName.Trim(), drow[col]);
                    }
                    DtRows.Add(newrow);
                }
                con.Close();


                return JSSerializer.Serialize(DtRows);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                List<String> Parameters = new List<String>();
                Parameters.Add("getRechargeCircleList");

             //   SendErrorMail(ex.ToString(), "getRechargeCircleList", Parameters);
               // Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
               // Context.Response.Write(@" {""Status"":""false"",""Message"" : ""Oops! Something went Wrong""}");
               // return;
            }
            return "false";
        }
```

web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings/>




  </connectionStrings>


  <system.web>

    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="32768"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
     <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <!--
        The <authentication> section enables configuration 
        of the security authentication mode used by 
        ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
    -->
   <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <!--
        The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
        of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
        during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
        it enables developers to configure html error pages 
        to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
         <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
         <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
        </customErrors>
    -->
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
  </system.web>
  <!-- 
      The system.webServer section is required for running ASP.NET AJAX under Internet
      Information Services 7.0.  It is not necessary for previous version of IIS.
  -->
  <system.webServer>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.serviceModel>

    <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttp" allowCookies="true"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="4194304" 
                 maxBufferSize="20000000"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="20000000">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" 
                 maxArrayLength="200000000"
                 maxStringContentLength="200000000"/>
        </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="SampleWcfproject.Service1Behavior" name="SampleWcfproject.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="SampleWcfproject.IService1">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="SampleWcfproject.SampleService1Behavior" name="SampleWcfproject.SampleService1">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="SampleWcfproject.ISampleService1">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
       <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="web">
                <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="SampleWcfproject.Service1Behavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="SampleWcfproject.SampleService1Behavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

i am getting the below respomse in visual studio by consuming the web reference project. But getting error like 400 in android.

[{""CircleID"":1,""CircleName"":""Andhra Pradesh""},{""CircleID"":4,""CircleName"":""Assam""},{""CircleID"":5,""CircleName"":""Bihar""},{""CircleID"":6,""CircleName"":""Chennai""},{""CircleID"":7,""CircleName"":""Delhi""},{""CircleID"":8,""CircleName"":""Gujarat""},{""CircleID"":9,""CircleName"":""Himachal Pradesh""},{""CircleID"":10,""CircleName"":""Haryana""},{""CircleID"":11,""CircleName"":""Jammu \u0026 Kashmir""},{""CircleID"":12,""CircleName"":""Kerala""},{""CircleID"":13,""CircleName"":""Karnataka""},{""CircleID"":14,""CircleName"":""Kolkata""},{""CircleID"":15,""CircleName"":""Maharashtra""},{""CircleID"":16,""CircleName"":""Madhya Pradesh""},{""CircleID"":17,""CircleName"":""Mumbai""},{""CircleID"":18,""CircleName"":""North East""},{""CircleID"":19,""CircleName"":""Orissa""},{""CircleID"":20,""CircleName"":""Punjab""},{""CircleID"":21,""CircleName"":""Rajasthan""},{""CircleID"":22,""CircleName"}]");

this is my url
http://xyzmnmkljj.in/SampleService1.svc/getdata

but it gives 400 bad request.

Any modifications in web.comfig file please help me

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check your IP is accessible to those machine if yes then you need to give the permission to that user to access the service. In this case you need to make the IIS setting changes to NTLM in provider.

[blogs.msdn.com](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/asiatech/archive/2012/01/30/400-bad-request-when-posting-webservice-or-wcf-request-from-ie.aspx)